# Input device to enter a number between 0 and 99?

Tags: input-device

I would like to have some sort of input device where a user can input a number between 0 and 99.  I'm envisioning something similar to a thermostat, where the user pushes the up or down arrow button and an LCD displays the number.

Where can I start?

Comment: There are several options a button or two, a numeric keypad, or a rotary encoder. You could get fancy and pair it with a 2 digit seven segment display, or an hd44780 lcd display. This tutorial http://fritzing.org/projects/fritzing-minikit-counting-knob is designed for an arduino, but a Google search should turn up similar for the Pi.

Comment: Since the part that @SteveRobillard posted is for arduino, it shouldn't be a big poblem to convert it to Pi. You'll just need to do scripting handling the circuit and you can change the display to any 2 digit led (you may want to look for common '-' to connect it to GPIO). RPi.GPIO python lib has ways to control stuff through events, so coding should be easy. First code the switch impulse counting, then handling the display.